# Overlapped Non Primary Key for Composite Foreign Key Doctrine Symfony 2

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys

I'm trying to construct four entities using Doctrine Symfony 2.


One of the entities has "Overlapped or Intersected Non Primary Key Composite Foreign Key" - apologize for my bad English.


I've tried to modify doctrine object but I can't still persist all the entities to PostgreSQL.



Below the doctrine objects of four entities I've constructed:

```
    <?php

    namespace EntityBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EntityBundle\EntityRepository\GeographyContinentRepository")
     * @ORM\Table(
     *     name="geography_continent",
     *     uniqueConstraints={
     *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="geography_continent_u1", columns={"continent_name"})
     *     }
     * )
     */
    class GeographyContinent
    {       
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        */
        protected $id;            

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="continent_name", type="string", nullable=false)
         */    
        protected $continentName;            

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", nullable=true)
         */    
        protected $description;        

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set continentName
         *
         * @param string $continentName
         * @return GeographyContinent
         */
        public function setContinentName($continentName)
        {
            $this->continentName = $continentName;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get continentName
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getContinentName()
        {
            return $this->continentName;
        }

        /**
         * Set description
         *
         * @param string $description
         * @return GeographyContinent
         */
        public function setDescription($description)
        {
            $this->description = $description;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get description
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getDescription()
        {
            return $this->description;
        }
    }

    ?>


    <?php

    namespace EntityBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EntityBundle\EntityRepository\GeographyCountryRepository")
     * @ORM\Table(
     *     name="geography_country",
     *     uniqueConstraints={
     *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="geography_country_u1", columns={"country_name"}),
     *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="geography_country_u2", columns={"telephone_code"}),
     *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="geography_country_u3", columns={"currency_name"}),
     *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="geography_country_u4", columns={"currency_symbol"})
     *     }
     * )
     */
    class GeographyCountry 
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        */
        protected $id;            

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="country_name", type="string", nullable=false)
         */    
        protected $countryName;            

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="telephone_code", type="string", nullable=true)
         */    
        protected $telephoneCode;            

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="currency_name", type="string", nullable=true)
         */    
        protected $currencyName;            

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="currency_symbol", type="string", nullable=true)
         */    
        protected $currencySymbol;                

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="continent_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
         */    
        protected $continentId;            

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GeographyContinent", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="continent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */    
        protected $fkContinent;            

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", nullable=true)
         */    
        protected $description;

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set countryName
         *
         * @param string $countryName
         * @return GeographyCountry
         */
        public function setCountryName($countryName)
        {
            $this->countryName = $countryName;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get countryName
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getCountryName()
        {
            return $this->countryName;
        }

        /**
         * Set telephoneCode
         *
         * @param string $telephoneCode
         * @return GeographyCountry
         */
        public function setTelephoneCode($telephoneCode)
        {
            $this->telephoneCode = $telephoneCode;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get telephoneCode
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getTelephoneCode()
        {
            return $this->telephoneCode;
        }

        /**
         * Set currencyName
         *
         * @param string $currencyName
         * @return GeographyCountry
         */
        public function setCurrencyName($currencyName)
        {
            $this->currencyName = $currencyName;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get currencyName
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getCurrencyName()
        {
            return $this->currencyName;
        }

        /**
         * Set currencySymbol
         *
         * @param string $currencySymbol
         * @return GeographyCountry
         */
        public function setCurrencySymbol($currencySymbol)
        {
            $this->currencySymbol = $currencySymbol;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get currencySymbol
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getCurrencySymbol()
        {
            return $this->currencySymbol;
        }

        /**
         * Set continentId
         *
         * @param integer $continentId
         * @return GeographyCountry
         */
        public function setContinentId($continentId)
        {
            $this->continentId = $continentId;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get continentId
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getContinentId()
        {
            return $this->continentId;
        }

        /**
         * Set description
         *
         * @param string $description
         * @return GeographyCountry
         */
        public function setDescription($description)
        {
            $this->description = $description;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get description
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getDescription()
        {
            return $this->description;
        }

        /**
         * Set fkContinent
         *
         * @param \EntityBundle\Entity\GeographyContinent $fkContinent
         * @return GeographyCountry
         */
        public function setFkContinent(\EntityBundle\Entity\GeographyContinent $fkContinent = null)
        {
            $this->fkContinent = $fkContinent;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get fkContinent
         *
         * @return \EntityBundle\Entity\GeographyContinent 
         */
        public function getFkContinent()
        {
            return $this->fkContinent;
        }
    }       

    ?>


    <?php

    namespace EntityBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EntityBundle\EntityRepository\GeographyProvinceRepository")
     * @ORM\Table(
     *     name="geography_province", 
     *     uniqueConstraints={
     *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="geography_province_u1", columns={"country_id", "id"}),
     *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="geography_province_u2", columns={"country_id", "province_name"})
     *     }
     * )
     */
    class GeographyProvince 
    {
        /**
        * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        */
        protected $id;            

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="province_name", type="string", nullable=false)
         */    
        protected $provinceName;        

        /**
        * @ORM\Column(name="country_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
        */
        protected $countryId;        

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GeographyCountry", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */    
        protected $fkCountry;            

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", nullable=true)
         */    
        protected $description;    

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set provinceName
         *
         * @param string $provinceName
         * @return GeographyProvince
         */
        public function setProvinceName($provinceName)
        {
            $this->provinceName = $provinceName;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get provinceName
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getProvinceName()
        {
            return $this->provinceName;
        }

        /**
         * Set countryId
         *
         * @param integer $countryId
         * @return GeographyProvince
         */
        public function setCountryId($countryId)
        {
            $this->countryId = $countryId;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get countryId
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getCountryId()
        {
            return $this->countryId;
        }

        /**
         * Set description
         *
         * @param string $description
         * @return GeographyProvince
         */
        public function setDescription($description)
        {
            $this->description = $description;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get description
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getDescription()
        {
            return $this->description;
        }

        /**
         * Set fkCountry
         *
         * @param \EntityBundle\Entity\GeographyCountry $fkCountry
         * @return GeographyProvince
         */
        public function setFkCountry(\EntityBundle\Entity\GeographyCountry $fkCountry = null)
        {
            $this->fkCountry = $fkCountry;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get fkCountry
         *
         * @return \EntityBundle\Entity\GeographyCountry 
         */
        public function getFkCountry()
        {
            return $this->fkCountry;
        }
    }

    ?>


    <?php

    namespace EntityBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EntityBundle\EntityRepository\GeographyCityRepository")
     * @ORM\Table(
     *     name="geography_city",
     *     uniqueConstraints={
     *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="geography_city_u1", columns={"province_id", "is_municipality", "city_name"})
     *     }
     * )
     */
    class GeographyCity 
    {
        /**
        * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        */
        protected $id;            

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="city_name", type="string", nullable=false)
         */    
        protected $cityName;        

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="is_municipality", type="boolean", nullable=true)
         */    
        protected $isMunicipality;            

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="province_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
         */    
        protected $provinceId;         

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="country_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
         */    
        protected $countryId;            

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GeographyCountry", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
         */    
        protected $fkCountry;            

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GeographyProvince", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumns
         * (
         *   {
         *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="country_id", nullable=false),
         *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="province_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
         *   }
         * )
         */    
        protected $fkProvince;            

        /**
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", nullable=true)
         */    
        protected $description;        

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set cityName
         *
         * @param string $cityName
         * @return GeographyCity
         */
        public function setCityName($cityName)
        {
            $this->cityName = $cityName;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get cityName
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getCityName()
        {
            return $this->cityName;
        }

        /**
         * Set isMunicipality
         *
         * @param boolean $isMunicipality
         * @return GeographyCity
         */
        public function setIsMunicipality($isMunicipality)
        {
            $this->isMunicipality = $isMunicipality;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get isMunicipality
         *
         * @return boolean 
         */
        public function getIsMunicipality()
        {
            return $this->isMunicipality;
        }

        /**
         * Set provinceId
         *
         * @param integer $provinceId
         * @return GeographyCity
         */
        public function setProvinceId($provinceId)
        {
            $this->provinceId = $provinceId;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get provinceId
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getProvinceId()
        {
            return $this->provinceId;
        }

        /**
         * Set countryId
         *
         * @param integer $countryId
         * @return GeographyCity
         */
        public function setCountryId($countryId)
        {
            $this->countryId = $countryId;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get countryId
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getCountryId()
        {
            return $this->countryId;
        }

        /**
         * Set description
         *
         * @param string $description
         * @return GeographyCity
         */
        public function setDescription($description)
        {
            $this->description = $description;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get description
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getDescription()
        {
            return $this->description;
        }

        /**
         * Set fkCountry
         *
         * @param \EntityBundle\Entity\GeographyCountry $fkCountry
         * @return GeographyCity
         */
        public function setFkCountry(\EntityBundle\Entity\GeographyCountry $fkCountry)
        {
            $this->fkCountry = $fkCountry;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get fkCountry
         *
         * @return \EntityBundle\Entity\GeographyCountry 
         */
        public function getFkCountry()
        {
            return $this->fkCountry;
        }

        /**
         * Set fkProvince
         *
         * @param \EntityBundle\Entity\GeographyProvince $fkProvince
         * @return GeographyCity
         */
        public function setFkProvince(\EntityBundle\Entity\GeographyProvince $fkProvince)
        {
            $this->fkProvince = $fkProvince;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get fkProvince
         *
         * @return \EntityBundle\Entity\GeographyProvince 
         */
        public function getFkProvince()
        {
            return $this->fkProvince;
        }
    }

    ?>
```

The four entities above able to generate SQL DDL PostgreSQL properly.

Below the generated sql (with few modifications):

```
    CREATE TABLE geography_continent 
    (
        id INT NOT NULL, 
        continent_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
        description VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE geography_country 
    (
        id INT NOT NULL, 
        continent_id INT NOT NULL, 
        country_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
        telephone_code VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
        currency_name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
        currency_symbol VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
        description VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE geography_province 
    (
        id INT NOT NULL, 
        country_id INT NOT NULL, 
        province_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
        description VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE geography_city 
    (
        id INT NOT NULL, 
        country_id INT NOT NULL, 
        province_id INT DEFAULT NULL, 
        city_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
        is_municipality BOOLEAN DEFAULT NULL, 
        description VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );

    CREATE SEQUENCE geography_continent_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1;
    CREATE SEQUENCE geography_country_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1;
    CREATE SEQUENCE geography_province_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1;
    CREATE SEQUENCE geography_city_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1;        
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX geography_continent_u1 ON geography_continent (continent_name);        
    CREATE INDEX IDX_6D7254DD921F4C77 ON geography_country (continent_id);
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX geography_country_u1 ON geography_country (country_name);
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX geography_country_u2 ON geography_country (telephone_code);
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX geography_country_u3 ON geography_country (currency_name);
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX geography_country_u4 ON geography_country (currency_symbol);        
    CREATE INDEX IDX_1657BF92F92F3E70 ON geography_province (country_id);
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX geography_province_u1 ON geography_province (country_id, id);
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX geography_province_u2 ON geography_province (country_id, province_name);        
    CREATE INDEX IDX_3F82CFCAF92F3E70 ON geography_city (country_id);
    CREATE INDEX IDX_3F82CFCAF92F3E70E946114A ON geography_city (country_id, province_id);
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX geography_city_u1 ON geography_city (province_id, is_municipality, city_name);

    ALTER TABLE geography_country ADD CONSTRAINT FK_6D7254DD921F4C77 FOREIGN KEY (continent_id) REFERENCES geography_continent (id) MATCH FULL ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
    ALTER TABLE geography_province ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1657BF92F92F3E70 FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES geography_country (id) MATCH FULL ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
    ALTER TABLE geography_city ADD CONSTRAINT FK_3F82CFCAF92F3E70 FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES geography_country (id) MATCH FULL ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;

    -- MATCH SIMPLE FOREIGN KEY
    ALTER TABLE geography_city ADD CONSTRAINT FK_3F82CFCAF92F3E70E946114A FOREIGN KEY (country_id, province_id) REFERENCES geography_province (country_id, id) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
```

Table "geography_city" have two foreign keys.

One refers to table "geography_country" with column "country_id".

The other refers to table "geography_province" with two columns "country_id" and "province_id", column "province_id" is optional and may NULL (signed as "MATCH SIMPLE" FOREIGN KEY) because perhaps A City of A Country does not have province.



Below main php code of the controller to persist the four entities above:

```
    <?php

    $geographyContinentName = "A Continent Name";
    $geographyContinent = new GeographyContinent();
    $geographyContinent->setContinentName($geographyContinentName);

    $geographyCountryName = "A Country Name";
    $geographyCountry = new GeographyCountry();
    $geographyCountry->setCountryName($geographyCountryName);
    $geographyCountry->setFkContinent($geographyContinent);

    $geographyProvinceName = "A Province Name";
    $geographyProvince = new GeographyProvince();
    $geographyProvince->setProvinceName($geographyProvinceName);
    $geographyProvince->setFkCountry($geographyCountry);

    $geographyCityName = "A City Name";
    $geographyCity = new GeographyCity();
    $geographyCity->setCityName($geographyCityName);
    $geographyCity->setFkCountry($geographyCountry);
    $geographyCity->setFkProvince($geographyProvince);

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManager->persist($geographyContinent);
    $entityManager->persist($geographyCountry);
    $entityManager->persist($geographyProvince);
    $entityManager->persist($geographyCity);
    $entityManager->flush();

    ?>
```

Below the errors produced after running the controller above:

```
    [2013-12-15 06:41:38] request.INFO: 
        Matched route "entity_geography_create"
        (
           parameters: 
               "_controller": "Entity\GeographyBundle\Controller\CreateController::indexAction", 
               "_route": "entity_geography_create"
        )

    [2013-12-15 06:41:38] app.ERROR: 
        Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: 
            An exception occurred while executing 
            'INSERT INTO geography_city (id, city_name, is_municipality, province_id, country_id, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
            with params [1, "A City Name", null, 1, null, null]
            SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation
            ERROR:  null value in column "country_id" violates not-null constraint 
            (uncaught exception) at D:\server\htdocs\application\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException.php line 47
```

I expect that value of column "country_id" will be provided automatically when inserting into table "geography_city", but based on the errors above it does not.



Any help I would really appreciate.

Thank you very much.

Best Regards.

Comment: What does not work? Did you have an error message?

Comment: Why don't you use an integer as an id in each of your table? I think that it will be easier to use as primary and foreign keys in all of your tables.

Comment: Please add the error messages in your question and remove them from the comments, it will be easier to read.

Comment: `country_id text NOT NULL,` This foreign key should be an integer, not a string.

Comment: @n.1 after additional experiments I still can not solve my problem, many thanks for your suggestion to fullfill more completely my problem information

Answer (score 1):

@n.1 Many thanks for your kind help.

My full transaction code running well.

I execute commands:

```
    php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
    php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
    php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
    php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup
```

My problem is solved now.

Thanks God.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem and solved it by calling `$entityManager->flush();` after every call to `$entityManager->persist($your_new_entity);`. It will ensure that the persisted entity will have an id, so this id will be available for the other entity which use it as a foreign key.

So you have to call

```
$entityManager->persist($your_new_entity);
$entityManager->flush();
```

before using the new entity as a foreign key.

It seems to be feasible by defining cascade operations, see the [documentation of Doctrine2 about Persisting entities](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#persisting-entities) for more information.